# generate number in sequence in both ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to generate numbers in sequence(continuous numbers) for both ng-repeat and for which i am using `$index` but that is again giving me sequence from 1 for second `ng-repeat`.
I tried taking a variable in scope and then incrementing in the view but that is also not working out.

[Example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2rgqE6E8NYj6e2vNO31p?p=preview)

Code:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
    <li><span>{{$index +  1}}</span><span> {{detail.name}}</span>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-repeat="detailed in details.name">
        <li><span>{{$index +  1}}</span><span>{{detailed.prof}}</span></li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.details = [
   { "name": "Employees" },
   { "name": "Support" }
    ];
     $scope.details.name = [
   { "prof": "enginerr" },
   { "prof": "doctor" }
    ];
});
```

here in this plunker engineer number should be 3 and doctor number should be 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `details.length` to the second `ng-repeat`

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
    <li><span>{{$index +  1}}</span><span> {{detail.name}}</span>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-repeat="detailed in details.name">
        <li><span>{{details.length + $index +  1}}</span><span>{{detailed.prof}}</span></li>
   </ul>
```